# Why .net will auto handle urldecode in running

Tags: c#, .net, url, urldecode

Windows 7 sp1
Visual Studio 2015
a winform project
.net version:4.0 client
I use httpclient to send a url with urlencode and want to Get json from a webserver.

```
var result = httpclient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
```

In VS debug or release mode,It runs no error.
But when it compiled into dll,exe and installed in windows.It will run with error(http 404).
I checked server log which log the request url,when I use debug in VS,the url contains '%2f'(because I use urlencode before).
But when I compile it,install it and run,the server log show the url replaced '%2f' to '/' (something do urldecode automatically).So occur the 404 error.

1. I suspect the VS debug .net runtime is different from windows's local .net runtime.
   But I write the code to print the version.The results show the same version number.

```
Environment.Version.ToString();
```

2. I change the httpclient to webclient,and the problem is still here.

Comment: There is something different in the request headers.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request headers to see what is different.

Comment: hi kimitop, can you please post more code ? What is done with "url" underways, what is the origin of "url" ? tip: use Debug.WriteLine() to report the request before you send it. Also, follow jdweng's suggestion, to install fiddler, to see in real time what's actually going on. e.g. are you sure your log viewer does not replace % encoded slashes.. fiddler will always report the literal ascii string sent.

Comment: Today,I use fiddler and find the url is already replaced '%2f' to '/'.The program and vshost send the different url. And I use `var result = httpclient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(Uri.escapeUriString(url))).Result;`,the '/' in url will replaced to '%252f' and not be replaced to '%2f'. And it doesn't occur 404 error. But the response json is not right,So I don't know why sometimes .Net will decode the url automatically and sometimes it won't.